How to repeat columns with new row data in Power BI to emulate horizontal pagination?
I have a list of projects in a spreadsheet that lists the facility and the go-live date for each.  For reports, I have to convert the long list of those three columns into multiple copies of the same three columns, side by side.  That way, I can either embed or screenshot the columns into a powerpoint slide.  I am trying to convert this process into a Power BI automation that builds the report based on a Microsot List.  So, I will import the spreadsheet into a list and then the report can be generated on schedule.
Here is what it looks like in the spreadsheet:

I have tried to play around with table and matrix visualizations and I cannot get this to work like I need it to.  Any suggestions?

You don't.  This is a data model problem, not a report problem.  In Power Query make three copies of the query, and edit each one so it has just one of the sets of columns, then append them all together.  The resulting table should just have 3 columns. eg

